# Can Google Calendar API support 'service account authorization without OAuth` method?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to implement authorization for a service account using without OAuth method to access Calendar API. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#jwt-auth

```
With some Google APIs, you can make authorized API calls using a signed JWT directly as a bearer token, rather than an OAuth 2.0 access token.

If the API you want to call has a service definition published in the Google APIs GitHub repository, you can make authorized API calls using a JWT instead of an access token. To do so:

Using any standard JWT library, such as one found at jwt.io, create a JWT with a header and payload like the following example:
```

```
    {
      "alg": "RS256",
      "typ": "JWT",
      "kid": "abcdef1234567890"
    }
    .
    {
      "iss": "123456-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
      "sub": "123456-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
      "aud": "https://firestore.googleapis.com/",
      "iat": 1511900000,
      "exp": 1511903600
    }
```

The above document mentions JWT `aud` field should be given as `https://SERVICE.googleapis.com/` format. Since the Calendar endpoint is not in the format, can this authorization mechanism be done to access Calendar API?

calendar endpoint is  `https://www.googleapis.com/`

Comment: Ha What? "without OAuth method" can we get a [example] of what your trying to do here? Authorization is out side of the API You are accessing. you shouldn't be concerned with the calendar endpoint while your trying to authorize your service account.

Comment: @DaImTo please check https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#jwt-auth. calendar endpoint is required in JWT ```aud``` field.

Comment: Why are you doing this manually?  Why aren't you using one of the libraries? Just so that you know I have been working with this for ten years and I have yet to manage to get service account authorization to work from the ground up.

Comment: @DaImTo I have a requirement to build using HTTP. I am able to do this in Sheet API as it has API endpoint ```https://sheets.googleapis.com/```. But Calendar API doesn't support it because of the endpoint.

Comment: Your still mixing service accounts and api endpoints.  I would love to see how you are able to create service account authorization with pure HTTP for Google sheets.

Comment: I generated a JWT in the Google-defined format in the document https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#jwt-auth and sent that JWT token as a bearer token in the Sheet API

Comment: Hi there @Shanan! I have been studying your question, but I don't understand the issue at hand. What is your end goal? Could you please clarify your actual situation?

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron I am unable to use Google Calendar in HTTP direct JWT service account authorization as Calendar is not in ```https://calendar.googleapis.com/``` endpoint format. Is it a limitation from Google?

Answer (score 0):

yes. Google provides Calendar service API endpoint as `https://calendar-json.googleapis.com/`.
https://support.google.com/workspacemigrate/answer/9222865?hl=en